# Why is the following typescript type union code invalid?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to create a function that either accepts a string or accepts a function that returns a string but I get the following error:

Code

```
interface Props {
    title: (values: string) => string | string;
}

const a: Props = {
    title: 'Title'
}

const b: Props = {
    title: (t) => t
}
```

Error:

```
Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
  Types of property 'title' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(values: string) => string'.
const a: Props
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Props%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20(values%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%20%7C%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20Props%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20'Title'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20Props%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20(t)%20%3D%3E%20t%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to wrap `(values: string) => string` in parentheses, otherwise union is applied to return type and reads `string | string`:

```
interface Props {
    title: ((values: string) => string) | string;
}
```

Slightly cleaner option would be extracting `(values: string) => string` to its own type:

```
type TitleBuilder = (values: string) => string;

interface Props {
    title: TitleBuilder | string;
}
```

Comment: I just discovered this myself, Thanks!